# SharePoint - Creating a Custom Search Results web Part Page

Tags: sharepoint

I have replaced the default Search Box in SharePoint using Delegate control.

Now my delegate control has a Text Box and a Button.

On Button Click it should take the users to a web part Page wich has all my Custom Web Parts added.

But this Web Part page should be accessible from every site in sharePoint as my Custom Delegate control can be added anywhere within the farm.

Ex: like OSSSearchResults.aspx but my custom web part page can be modified by users.

Can some one tell me how to do this?

Comment: Are you using Team site or Publishing site? For me, it is not clear what are you trying do.

Comment: Delegate Control can be added to any site (If I am not wrong).
I have created an aspx page and added my Web Parts to it and deployed it in 12\LAYOUTS. But this page cannot be editable. Can I do something like a Web Part Page and make it available from every site?

Thanks

carol

Answer (score -1):

You can put url of the custom results page in Search settings in site collection administration section.

Also You can customize the default search results page with out of the box webparts like SearchCoreResults webpart, refinement pane, search box etc.

But my question is can i add a custom webpart to this results.aspx.

Comment: If you have a separate question, create a separate question for it.